# How to insert date to MySQL from html input?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, date

I've problem with inserting a date `enter code here`into a MySQL database. On my webpage i've got a input which type is 'date' but there is a problem with inserting value of this input into database properly.

```
$connection->query("INSERT INTO users VALUES(NULL, '$nick', '$password_hash', '$email',".$_POST['gender'].",".$_POST['bday'].")")
```

Have you got any solution for my problem?

Comment: Apart from the answers given, make sure your post is the same format as MySQL needs it (yyyy-mm-dd). If it's not, use PHP's `date()` function to change it.

Comment: Is your problem resolved with any of given answer below ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code. you forget Single quote (').

```
$connection->query("INSERT INTO users VALUES(NULL, '$nick', '$password_hash', '$email','".$_POST['gender']."','".$_POST['bday']."')")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes around date value and using column name is good practice

```
 $connection->query("INSERT INTO users VALUES(NULL, '$nick', '$password_hash', '$email','".$_POST['gender']."','".$_POST['bday']."')")
```

Answer (score 0):

You incorrect syntax of MySQL

```
$connection->query("INSERT INTO users VALUES(NULL, '$nick', '$password_hash', '$email',".$_POST['gender'].",".$_POST['bday'].")")
```

Correct syntax

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Link refe: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

I hope help you

Answer (score 0):

try this code, single quotes around the variables and I don't see the need of writing $_POST[], because you can access the variables simply by using their name

`$connection->query("INSERT INTO users VALUES(NULL, '$nick', '$password_hash', '$email','$gender,'$bday'"));`

Answer (score 0):

$connection->query("INSERT INTO users VALUES(NULL, '$nick', '$password_hash', '$email','".$_POST['gender']."','".$_POST['bday']."')")